# Why do I have more users than I should on uptime

Tags: monitoring

on running the uptime command, it tells me that I have 5 users logged in. I don't understand this since I have on one user registered on this computer. This is the output

```
11:07:19 up 5 days,  1:11,  5 users,  load average: 0.42, 0.67, 0.56
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

every terminal window you have opened also counts as a login. Open more terminals and type the command again and you will see how the number changes

Comment: thanks, I've always seen number of users keep changing randomly and just ignore it.